# In .net vb is there a way to know if Yes or No was chosen in a SHELL command when User Account control appears

Tags: vb.net

I am using .net vb ; I usually shell a program to run an update of my software; the problem I am facing is I don't know whether the user has chosen Yes or No when prompted to run the program in an alleviated mode i.e When the User Account control box appears.

How can I know whether Yes or No was chosen after the shell command was issued. .

This is my current code - I use runas for a higher windows then XP

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateElevated()
        Try
            'Shell(C_Drive & "\POS-UPD\pos-upd.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False)

            Dim osInfo As OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion

            Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = C_Drive & "\POS-UPD"
            startInfo.FileName = C_Drive & "\POS-UPD\pos-upd.exe"
            If osInfo.Version.Major >= 6 Then startInfo.Verb = "runas"
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            Process.Start(startInfo)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do **not** write empty catch clauses like that.  Remove try/catch and it will be quite obvious what happens when you select "No".  Now put them back and catch the Win32Exception, its ErrorCode property tells you why it failed.

Comment: Thank you so much for steering me in the right direction ! I came right